# Is it possible for postgresdb (greenplum) to publish messages whenever the data inside to DB is updated?

Tags: database, postgresql, caching, synchronization, greenplum

I'm trying to sync the cache (gemfire) to be the same as the greenplum database. The database receives data updates from external sources.

I thought of using the database to send a trigger whenever the data in the database is updated, but I was wondering if there is a way for the database to publish messages to external sources.

There is a notify function in greenplum, so is it possible for Kafka or Gemfire to listen to the same channel that greenplum is notifying messages to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension like pg_amqp with greenplum to relay messages to a broken like rabbitmq for example. After you set up this extension, the greenplum rule system (https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Greenplum/6/greenplum-database/ref_guide-sql_commands-CREATE_RULE.html) can be used to decide when to sent messages.

Example:
create rule customers_ins as on insert to customers do select  amqp.publish(1,'','customersQ','Newval:'||new.id);